# DiscordJS Collector don´t Collect Message

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

My DiscordJS Interaction Message Collector doesn´t collect a Message. After the time ends, the bot only tells me "0 Items Collected"

```
const { EmbedBuilder, MessageReaction } = require("discord.js");
const { registerFont, createCanvas, loadImage } = require('canvas');
const scale = 20;
const canvas = createCanvas(171*scale,138*scale);
const fs = require('fs');
const sql = require('./../self-modules/sql.js');

const filter = m => m.content.includes('discord');

exports.run = async (client, interaction, dbcon) => {
    interaction.reply({content: "test", fetchReply: true}).then( (message) =>{
        const filter = (reaction, user) => {
            return reaction.emoji.name === '' && user.id === message.author.id;
        };
        
        const collector = message.createReactionCollector({ filter, time: 15000 });
        
        collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
            console.log(`Collected ${reaction.emoji.name} from ${user.tag}`);
        });
        
        collector.on('end', collected => {
            console.log(`Collected ${collected.size} items`);
        });
    });
}
```

Output (nothing else):

```
Collected 0 items
```

Here is my code, can somebody help?

my goal is, that after a user executed the Slash-Command, the Slash ask a question to the user and than a answer is required.

Thanks

#################################################################

I also tried this:

```
const { EmbedBuilder, MessageReaction } = require("discord.js");
const { registerFont, createCanvas, loadImage } = require('canvas');
const scale = 20;
const canvas = createCanvas(171*scale,138*scale);
const fs = require('fs');
const sql = require('./../self-modules/sql.js');

const filter = m => m.content.includes('discord');

exports.run = async (client, interaction, dbcon) => {
        interaction.reply({content: "test", fetchReply: true}).then( (message) =>{
            interaction.channel.awaitMessages({ max: 1, time: 30000, errors: ['time'] })
                .then(collected => {
                    interaction.followUp(`${collected.first().author} got the correct answer!`);
                })
                .catch(collected => {
                    interaction.followUp('Looks like nobody got the answer this time.');
                });
        });
}
```

Same result

Comment: I see that the filter is defined multiple times.
But even if i remove one definition, it doesnt work. Even without a filter, the Bot tells me, that nothing was collected.

Comment: Using `user.id === message.author.id` in your filter will let you collect reactions made by the bot only as `message.author` is your bot.

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros 
Good Point. 
But even if the Filter is 
`const filter = (reaction, user) => {
            return reaction.emoji.name === '';
};`

It didn´t work.

Comment: Try `console.log`ing inside the filter, does it execute at all?

Comment: I've just written an answer and after reading your question again I'm wondering if you want to collect reactions or messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment above, using `user.id === message.author.id` in your filter will let you collect reactions made by the bot only as `message.author` is your bot. If you want to accept reactions from the user who used the command, you can compare `user.id` to the `interaction.user.id`.

If it still doesn't work like that, you'll need to check the intents you enabled. You will need `Guilds`, `GuildMessages`, and `GuildMessageReactions` to collect reactions:

```js
const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageReactions,
  ],
});
```

The following should work as expected:

```js
exports.run = async (client, interaction, dbcon) => {
  interaction.reply({ content: 'test', fetchReply: true }).then((message) => {
    const filter = (reaction, user) =>
      reaction.emoji.name === '' && user.id === interaction.user.id;

    const collector = message.createReactionCollector({
      filter,
      time: 15000,
    });

    collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
      console.log(`Collected ${reaction.emoji.name} from ${user.tag}`);
    });

    collector.on('end', (collected) => {
      console.log(`Collected ${collected.size} items`);
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: Hi, Yes, i was missing this Intent "GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,"
Thank you very much